# Term for the non-reference category for a dummy variable

Tags: categorical-encoding

For a dummy variable, what is a non-reference category called? Is there a general term for these categories other than non-reference categories?

Comment: For a categorical variable with $k$ levels, there is one reference category and $k-1$ non-reference category, so the "the" isn't clear ...

Comment: Fair enough. So we have one reference category and one or more non-reference categories. What else can we call these other categories, other than non-reference categories.

Comment: I have never seen a specific name for those

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen any specific name for this but I think 'non-reference category' is clear enough. That said, there is likely to be a nicer way to phrase your point than using this slightly awkward phrase.